# Fuel download returns empty bytes?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using Fuel library for Kotlin to download an image.

The following code works as far as showing the download status ... but, the `Log.e("fetchProfileImage", "bytes --> ${bytes.size}")` line yields "0" for byte size, so I'm confused as to what's going on.

Is this the expected behavior, or am I doing something wrong?

```
        Fuel.download(endpoint).destination { response, url ->
            File.createTempFile("profileImage", ".jpg")
        }.progress { readBytes, totalBytes ->
            val fractionCompleted = readBytes.toFloat() / totalBytes.toFloat()
            this.delegate?.downloadProgressDidChange(to = fractionCompleted)
        }.response { request, response, result ->
            val (data, error) = result
            if (error != null) {
                Log.e("fetchProfileImage", "error: ${error}")
            } else {
                result.fold({ bytes ->

                    Log.e("fetchProfileImage", "bytes --> ${bytes.size}")
                    // delegate?.didReceiveProfileImage(bmp)
                }, {err ->
                    Log.e("fetchProfileImage", "error: ${err}")
                })
            }
        }
```

Here's the response:

```
Response : OK 
Length : 426828
Body : (426828 bytes of image/jpeg)
Headers : (8)
Content-Length : [426828]
Content-Type : [image/jpeg]
Date : [Mon, 12 Feb 2018 04:10:27 GMT]
Server : [Jetty(9.4.3.v20170317)]
X-Android-Received-Millis : [1518408627531]
X-Android-Response-Source : [NETWORK 200]
X-Android-Selected-Protocol : [http/1.1]
X-Android-Sent-Millis : [1518408627121]
```

Comment: Could you please post what is the value of result in the response callback, i.e., Log.e("fetchProfileImage", request.toString())

Comment: Request:  "Body : (empty)" "Headers : (1)" Accept-Encoding : compress;q=0.5, gzip;q=1.0

Comment: Response: In edited question above.

Comment: Could you please post the value of data in the else block of response callback, as it goes for the else block, because there's no problem with regards to establishing the connection with server as we are getting the value of response as "200".

Comment: What I’ve posted is from the else block

Comment: I am getting this problem too.

Comment: do you still have this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with the internal workings of Fuel

I have raised a pr that fixes this issue (in a suitable manner I hope) https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel/issues/275

This is not something you as a user have done wrong